# Eclipse problem when install new software

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, helios

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) for mac os X. I downloaded from the Eclipse download page, unzip and put it in Applications folder. Then, i start the Eclipse and choose the workspace (the default, Documents/Workspace). After this, i tried to install new software by going to Help->Install New Software. The problem is that a error occur with the following message:
"Cannot complete the request. This installation has not been configured properly for software update. See the error log for details."

And the error log has:
"Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file."

I'm trying to do this because i wanna install ADT for android developments (and i can't perform the very first step of the "how to").

What i can do to fix this??

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11):

Most likely, this is caused by a bug in an old version of The Unarchiver that corrupts the default profiles included with eclipse. Upgrade to the newest version of The Unarchiver, extract eclipse again, and everything ought to work.

Comment: I had the same symptom, and this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I uninstall the Unarchiver. Unzip with native utility in Mac and runs like a charm.

Comment: Paul - i a blown away! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. Of all the things .. who knew! Would put up 10+ if i could

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks Alot Paul :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is because the links for adding dependency packages aren't setup in Eclipse. Ensure that http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6 and hxxp://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/helios (replace xx with tt) are listed under Available Software Sites (under Help -> Install New Software). Once theses are present Eclipse should be able to download all the dependancies it needs for ADT.

Comment: The error is in help -> Install New Software, so i can't do that. I went to preferences -> Install/update -> Available Software Sites and the http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6 is already there ( i did reload to ensure is ok) and try to add hxxp://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/helios (replacing xx with tt), but this give me "Not found".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Eventually I downloaded a different package (actually I tried a couple of different versions, they both had different bugs). Give that a burl, and if it works you just install the plugins for the work you're doing.