# Cannot install Eclipse Plugins

Tags: eclipse

I have the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Juno) installed, and when I went to try to install plugins, Eclipse spat this:

*!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 2 0 2013-02-24 20:54:28.703
!MESSAGE Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file.*

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/12911938/6309 help? Or rather http://stackoverflow.com/a/5178306/6309 ?

Comment: Thank you! It worked, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: great! What has worked exactly?